# Install Magento Inventory after Magento installation using composer.json

Tags: magento2

I have install Magento-2.3.6 using github, but after the installation some of the Magento modules are missing like Magento_InventorySalesApi and others inventory. I want to install Smilesuite elasticsearch but the Magento inventory are missing. Is their anyways to install inventory using composer.json and I have also searched for installing modules inventory but its showes to add metadata in composer. So help us to install Inventory module.

Comment: have you tried composerinstall or composer update command

Comment: yes, but that doesn't worked. I have searched but can't find much related to it.

Comment: How can I install metadata using composer, somewhere its mentioned that for installing magento inventory you can use metadata to install.